# admob : Ads diffusion limited

Tags: flutter, admob

I recently have problem with my Google Admob account and Google block my account temporarily because their say their are incorrect traffic in my account (but I don't do anything such as click on ads that appear on my apps).

Their reactivated my account few day ago and I try to add some ads code to my new application. Before going to production,  I test ads with "Ad test" And all work perfect.

But when I use my real app ID for pub, I don't see add or I see a black screen where ad suppose to be. And this morning, I saw Google send me a mail that say their limited ads diffusion because their mention incorrect traffic on my account buy I don't make action such as clicking to ads.

I don't understand what really happen when their say I have incorrect traffic.

Should I not open my app when I put ads on it and how can I do to avoid this issue for the next time?

Thanks.
(Sorry for my English)

Comment: Google is blocking the new ad mob account for no reason. Try to use other ads networks like facebook or unity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

wait for few days
google will analyze your traffic and they'll remove ad limits after completing their analyze.

may be you have small userbase or you got sudden ad request by many user. In this case, admob will add your account in Ad limited criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have actually 2 app punlish in play store i publish them recently) . Their have both few user. You can found it with these url: 1) https://autem-services.fr/dir_wp/count_app/index.html. 2) https://autem-services.fr/dir_wp/eco_light/index.html

Comment: In the first app I include interstitial ad when user is in result screen and go back to home screen. But no ads show up when I try to perform userflow to show interstitial ad. In 2 app, I put 2 ads format: interstitial and banner. Banner normally appear when you get to home screen and interstitial when you leave the app. But no banner appear and I have in console "no config ad" ( but with test ad, all work perfectly). For intestinal when I leave app I have black screen and I need to press back key to exit from application.

Comment: I make test yesterday and this morning I got the message that ads diffusion are limited because their see incorrect traffic. I never click on ads because they never appear on both app. So I don't understand why I got these email.

Comment: As I said, wait for few days.
these could be you first apps or you might have stop requesting ad for a period of time.
So, Let them monitor your users.